# Macbook Pro resolution difference 13inch VS 15inch (March/May 2015 models)

Tags: mac, macbook, resolution, macbook-pro

I have a question about supported resolutions on Macbooks (2015).

The apple site states that the 13" Pro model supports, with Intel Iris 6100 graphics, a resolution of **3840 x 2160**.

The 15" Pro model which is 700+ US$ more, only supports a resolution of **2560 x 1600**.

**Now, interestingly, only the German Apple site says so.**
On the U.S. Apple site, both models have the same supported external resolution of 3840 x 2160.

**What's the difference between "Intel Iris 6100" and "Intel Iris PRO"?**

Is this a typo or this this "by design", meaning the German model has a lower resolution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3840 x 2160 is for external displays, in fact if you look at the hdmi interface you can actually drive 4096-by-2160 resolution at 24Hz with either processor.

2560 x 1600 is the native resolution of the 13", and where it's mentioned on the 15"'s specs that's a typo; probably someone at apple's translation service copy-pasting and grabbing the wrong number. As that section is describing the maximum resolution that external displays can add up to, and in reality is the same for each card.

As for the difference between "Intel Iris 6100" and "Intel Iris PRO", that's not my area of expertise. But you need a faster card to deal with the higher resolution of the built in display, which is why they use different cards.